# Vue filter - Return object depending on search input

Tags: javascript, filter, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this search input:

```
<input type="text" v-model="searchHero" placeholder="Search Hero">
```

And this "output" area:

```
<div class="item wrapper" v-for="hero in filterSearch">
  {{ hero.image }} <br>
  {{ hero.name }} <br>
  {{ hero.bookmark }} <br>
</div>
```

The idea is that the user searches a hero, and the output should show only the hero he is searching for. For example, if he starts typing `Ir`, the output area should show `Iron Man` and `Iron Man2`

This is the full vue js code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    searchHero: '',
    heroes: [
      { name: 'Spiderman', image: true, bookmark: 'Bookmarkhere' },
      { name: 'Hulk', image: true, bookmark: 'Bookmarkhere' },
      { name: 'Iron Man', image: true, bookmark: 'Bookmarkhere' },
      { name: 'Captain America', image: true, bookmark: 'Bookmarkhere' },
      { name: 'Iron Man2', image: true, bookmark: 'Bookmarkhere' }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filterSearch() {
      return this.heroes.filter( heroes => {
        return heroes.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
  }
});
```

I get the following error in the console:

**[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"
(found in )**

I believe that the problem is with the filderSearch(), but I cannot see what.

Here is the entire jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prozik/no2uLgrd/

Note: Replace `<div class="item wrapper" v-for="hero in filterSearch">` to

`<div class="item wrapper" v-for="hero in heroes">` if you want to see all the heroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter expression is a little off, try this

```js
computed: {
  filterSearch() {
    return this.heroes.filter( hero => {
      return !this.searchHero ||
        hero.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchHero.toLowerCase()) > -1
  })
}
```

}

Note that javascript array filter passes in each item individually, one at a time (you have coded as if the whole list was passed in).

Also added `!searchHero` so that all are displayed when search is empty.

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgz25ha1/)

Comment: I think even though he called the variable heroes, he was treating it as an individual item. It's probably the !this.searchHero thing that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter name heros needed to be hero.

```
filterSearch () {
  return this.heroes.filter(hero => {
    return hero.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchHero.toLowerCase())
  })
}
```

It's also advisable to add `:key="hero.id"` to your v-for loop in the template.
[Vue Cheat Sheet](https://www.vuemastery.com/vue-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Could you show the code that uses includes() to solve the problem?

Comment: Updated post above with includes method.

Comment: Please do not add the code in comments, use edit post function.

Comment: How is your code sample different to the original filter is the question (aside from variable names)?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this.

much cleaner and readable code.

```
filterSearch() {
  return this.heroes.filter( hero => {
    return hero.name.toLowerCase().match(this.searchHero.toLowerCase())
  })
}
```

Let me know how it works. Good Luck!